# What do two aliases for a table in FROM clause mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm analyzing a query looks like this.

```sql
FROM <theSameTableName> <theSameAlias>,
     (SELECT a, b
      FROM <theSameTableName>
      WHERE c = 'd'
      GROUP BY a, b) <theSameAlias>
WHERE
    <theSameAlias>.a =
```

What do they mean?

Comment: Are all three aliases the same one, or are they different names?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes!

Comment: @JinKwon . . . If the aliases are the same, the query will generate an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the query is trying to get data from two tables: 
(1) from a table and (2) from a sub query. So two aliases are used

For example:

```
SELECT o.*, p.*
FROM Orders o,
     (SELECT Name, Type
      FROM Products
      WHERE c = 'd'
      GROUP BY Name, Type) p
WHERE
    o.OrderDate = '01/01/2020' and p.Type = 'Shorts'
```

Comment: Would you please take a look at edited question? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use the same alias twice in the FROM clause